# How to archieve similar particle effect

Tags: animation

While wathcing the trailer to the upcoming plugin "Stardust", at 00:13 mark of the video, there can be seen a particle effect that resembles a orb of power;

[image: effect]

Since this plugin is not out yet, does anyone know how to archieve a similar effect as shown in the picture? To see it in motion [click here.](https://youtu.be/K8hvPXSj5ec?t=11s)

Comment: Your picture link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It goes by pretty quickly! It looks to me like they've taken a frame of something that is white at the bottom and producing purple particles upwards, and then applied a rectangular to polar distortion to it, or possibly wrapped it into a 3D sphere.